# Get path of image C#

Tags: c#, wpf, path

I have a image-path that must be inserted into following code:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\dir\private- name\Easy\Easy_v\Easy_v\Attempts\image.jpg");
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

When I need to change this path, I'm trying to get path with a function I've written, but when I inserted the full path into the `uri`, this character: `\` has been replaced with `/`

Any way to get the correct image path, and replace it with the one above?

Comment: Maybe just change `/` into \?

Comment: you should still be able to read the file, even though it uses `/`. What actual *problem* are you trying to solve?

Comment: @RB. couldn't you have fixed the title and the spelling errors as well, when you were editing? Seems unneccessary to skip those.

Comment: @RB. haha :) well, I agree with you, that code formatting should be correct. I also feel that questions should be edited, but they should be edited completely.. That's why I asked [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169690/require-substantial-edits-when-editing) (and this is a good example, now on its 5th edit)..

Comment: @Default Brilliantly, someone has now undone my code-edit anyway! I think I might go and check the taps are off...

Comment: Doesn't look as though it was ever formatted, as I also formatted the code, then the edit was denied.

Comment: Assuming the image exists, the code posted will work. However, you state: `When I need to change this path, I'm trying to get path with a function I've written...`. Sounds like the function needs to be reviewed; can you post your function that is getting the path?

Comment: @RB. haha, you're funny :) and yet, on its 6th edit the [title still contains a tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147063)

Comment: @plast1K Yeah it was. Check out edits [#2](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15551353/2) and [#3](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15551353/3) :)

Comment: Yeah, saw that, was formatted on edit #2, then back to whitespace on edit 3#, that's annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Uri class has a property called

```
uri.LocalPath
```

this is the fullpath name expressed according to the local system preferences
of course you can apply the normal Path methods to this property

```
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetDirectoryName(uri.LocalPath));
```

[See MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.localpath%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)